# Extract Terraform IP with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, terraform

I need help in extracting ips to Jenkins pipeline. We use terraform/aws to create instance and we just created json.tf file with all ips I want to extract those ips into Jenkins work space. can someone please provide a script to extract ip into Jenkins work space before building the environment with that ips.

Comment: Sounds more like a jenkins question rather than a terraform question? Tag your question appropriately please. What do you mean by 

> _extract ips into Jenkins work space_

Comment: You should call Jenkins pipeline via its token from user-data in that ec2 instance.

Comment: You can also use Provisioners to write ips into a file or  set them to an environment variable(s) and access them from the pipeline script

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option here is to ensure that your list of IPs is in the same format as accepted by a variable file for Terraform; further reading here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#variable-files.

That could look something like this:

```
# variables.tfvars
ip_addresses = [
  "1.1.1.1",
  "2.2.2.2"
]

# your_file.tf
resource "aws_instance" "instances" {
  count = "${length(var.ip_addresses)}"

  ami           = "ami-12345"
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
}
```

Then, when running your configuration; your command would look like:

`terraform apply -var-file=variables.tfvars`